# Access S3 location with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a report from APS in a location. For instances:

```
s3://aps-reporting-entweb/aps-download-publisher-loleilololailo/reportId=workingonsaturdaystastesgood/executionDate=theday/
```

This is what appears in the APS UI. How can I fetch that report with python?. I don't see any bucket name anywhere.

Can I assignt it to any result similar to:

```
os.system(aws s3 [code] location
```

Comment: Have you [searched SO for "boto3 S3"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=boto3+s3)? As of this writing, I see 8059 results. The bucket name is the substring that comes just after `'s3://'` and before the next `'/'`.

Comment: First, you would need a set of AWS credentials that have permission to access the bucket. You can save them in a configuration file by using the AWS CLI `aws configure` command. You can then use the AWS SDK for Python [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) to access the bucket.